# Applying the value of one field to multiple records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to know the best way to apply the value of one form field to multiple records in rails.

I will have a view that renders partials where each partial will create a record.  The record will have an association, quantity, and category.  I want the user to be able to type in one category for multiple records but I cannot find any way to do this.

Effectively, I want the user to use a form like:

`Cat1 Item1 1
     Item2 2
     Item3 3
Cat2 Item4 4
     Item5 5
Cat3 Item6 6
Cat4 Item7 7`

and have it create the records like:

`Cat1 Item1 1
Cat1 Item2 2
Cat1 Item3 3
Cat2 Item4 4
Cat2 Item5 5
Cat3 Item6 6
Cat4 Item7 7`

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this in my project, but it's a bit complicated.

I use javascript on the page so that whenever the user enters a new item under a category then another blank filed appears in the form for the next item. Each item's field names and ids are suffixed with "__n" where n is a counter that increments so all the names and ids are unique and matching for the items, something like this:

```
<div class="category-input" id="cat1" >
  <h2>Category 1</h2>
  <div class="record-input">
    <input type="text" name="cat1-item-name__0" />
    <input type="number" name="cat1-item-amount__0" />
  </div
  <div class="record-input">
    <input type="text" name="cat1-item-name__1" />
    <input type="number" name="cat1-item-amount__1" />
  </div
</div>
```

Then in the controller I have to sort through all the parameters and create records for each. I put the values into hashes to make it easier like this:

```
categories.each do |cat|
  items = Hash[params.select{ |param| param[/^#{cat}-item-name__\d+$/] }.map{ |k,v| [k.split('__').last,v] }]
  amounts = Hash[params.select{ |param| param[/^#{cat}-item-amount__\d+$/] }.map{ |k,v| [k.split('__').last,v] }]
  # make records for category `cat` from these hashes
end
```